# core dumped assembly failure on recursive call

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, towers-of-hanoi

I am a computer science student and I am developing a code about the hanoi tower to be presenting in my class here in Brazil. I'm getting the error of segmentation failure, and after a long time testing the error seems this in the first recurisva call of the function hanoi, but I am new and without experience in the subject, could someone help me? Sorry some variables are in Portuguese.

```
section .data

    SYS_WRITE:  equ 4
    STD_OUT:    equ 1
    SYS_READ:  equ 3
    STD_IN:    equ 1


    rod:        dd 0x33 ;Quantidade de discos
    from_rod:   dd 0x31 ;Vai da primeira estaca
    to_rod:     dd 0x33 ;Para o terceiro
    aux_rod:    dd 0x32 ;Usando o segundo como aux

    auxiliar:   dd 0x0

    msgpt1: db 0xa, "Mover disco ", 0
    msgpt1_len: equ $-msgpt1

    msgpt2: db " da estaca ", 0
    msgpt2_len: equ $-msgpt2

    msgpt3: db " para a ", 0
    msgpt3_len: equ $-msgpt3

    signal: db "*", 0
    signallen: equ $-signal

    linebreak: db 0xA
    linebreak_len: equ $-linebreak


section .text
    global _start
    %macro print 2
        mov     eax, SYS_WRITE
        mov     ebx, STD_OUT
        mov     ecx, %1
        mov     edx, %2
        syscall
    %endmacro


_start:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 0x10

    mov eax, [rod]
    mov dword[ebp-0x4], eax
    mov eax, [from_rod]
    mov dword[ebp-0x8], eax
    mov eax, [to_rod]
    mov dword[ebp-0xC], eax
    mov eax, [aux_rod]
    mov dword[ebp-0x10], eax

    call hanoi


    print linebreak, linebreak_len


    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80


hanoi:
    mov eax, 0x31
    cmp eax, dword[ebp-0x4]
    je printHanoi ;

    mov eax, dword[ebp-0x4]
    mov ebx, dword[ebp-0x8]
    mov ecx, dword[ebp-0xC]
    mov edx, dword[ebp-0x10]

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 0x10

    dec eax
    mov dword[ebp-0x4], eax
    mov dword[ebp-0x8], ebx
    mov dword[ebp-0xC], edx
    mov dword[ebp-0x10], ecx

    call hanoi

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    call printsignal
    call printHanoi

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 0x10

    dec eax
    mov dword[ebp-0x4], eax
    mov dword[ebp-0x8], edx
    mov dword[ebp-0xC], ecx
    mov dword[ebp-0x10], ebx

    call hanoi

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    ret

printHanoi:
    print msgpt1, msgpt1_len    ;Imprime "Mover disco "

    mov eax, dword[ebp-0x4]     ;Acessa a qtd de disco (N)
    mov [auxiliar], eax         
    print auxiliar, 1           ;Imprime N

    print msgpt2, msgpt2_len    ;Imprime " da estaca "

    mov eax, dword[ebp-0x8]     ;Acessa o from_rod
    mov [auxiliar], eax
    print auxiliar, 1           ;Imprime from_rod

    print msgpt3, msgpt3_len    ;Imprime " para a "

    mov eax, dword[ebp-0xC]     ;Acessa o to_rod
    mov [auxiliar], eax
    print auxiliar, 1           ;Imprime o to_rod

    ;Restaurando registradores
    mov eax, dword[ebp-0x4]
    mov ebx, dword[ebp-0x8]
    mov ecx, dword[ebp-0xC]
    mov edx, dword[ebp-0x10]

    ret


printsignal:
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STD_OUT
    mov ecx, signal
    mov edx, signallen
    int 0x80

    ret
```

Comment: If you're going to use EBP as a frame pointer, set it up on function entry.  Don't make assumptions about the caller's stack frame to load your args.  ESP points to your args, you shouldn't assume anything about the incoming EBP value.  As for your bug, if that wasn't the problem then use a debugger and find out which instruction faults.  Debugging asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfolded: a waste of your time, and everyone else's on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Or if you do want to use the caller's register values, it might be more efficient to take args in registers instead of on the stack.